# ¿Porque la imagen se distorsiona cuando es una conexion local (2 pc's) pero funciona correctamente cuando es en la misma pc?

Tags: c#, socket, serialización

tengo un pequeño problema, estoy haciendo una transmision de video entre 2 pc por conexion TCP, lo que hago es tomar una screenshot de la pantalla, serializarla y enviarla a la otra pc, hice pruebas desde una sola pc y todo va muy bien pero cuando me conecto a la segunda pc la imagen se distorsiona si uso MemoryStream pero la actualizacion de imagen es rapida pero si uso BinaryFormatter la imagen llega correctamente pero tarda en actualizarse la imagen, aqui un ejemplo:

Esta imagen es con MemoryStream
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el nuevo codigo que me arreoja la excepxion ArgumentException:

```
public static void SerializeScreen(Stream stream, Bitmap Image)
    {
        BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        binaryWriter.Write(memory.ToArray());
    }

    public static Image DeserializeScreen(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] Buffer = new byte[500000];
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        int Bytes;
        int LastPost = 0;
        do
        {
            Bytes = binaryReader.Read(Buffer, LastPost, Buffer.Length - LastPost);
            LastPost += Bytes;
        } while (Bytes > 0);
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(Buffer);
        return Image.FromStream(memory);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta linea de código "stream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);" no garantiza que se lea el stream completo, debes hacer un ciclo hasta que se lea toda la imagen, algo asi como:

```
int lastPos = 0; //ultima posición del buffer con datos
int readBytes = 0; //cantidad de bytes leidos en el ciclo

do
{

       readBytes = stream.Read(Buffer, lastPos , Buffer.Length);
       lastPos +=readBytes;
 

}
while (readBytes>0)
```

Comment: Gracias amiggo, solo una cosa, lo que pasa es que usando esa manera el ""Image.FromStream()"" me salta una excepcion despues de la primera vez que se llamo al metodo deserialize

Comment: ¿Que excepción te da?, ¿puedes postear el codigo?

Comment: Listo amigo, ya agregue el codigo

Comment: fijate que esto: Buffer.Length - LastPost no de negativo..

Comment: @gbianchi no amigo, no da negativo, el problema es cuando quiere convertir los datos del memorystream a Image

Comment: no puedes pasar el buffer completo al memory stream, solo los bytes que correspondan a la imagen, te sugiero que crees el memory stream vacio y luego uses el metodo write: memory.write(buffer, 0, lastPos); lastPost deberia contener el numero de bytes leidos